# JSdoc: node element type in function argument

Tags: javascript

I have an function that checks if the element is an valid HTML element.

```
export function isValid(element) {
  return element.toString() !== "[object HTMLUnknownElement]";
}
```

I want to comment this function but i dont know what data type i should use for the param. Its an node element.

```
/**
* @param {Object} element - Node element that is being checked
* @returns {Boolean}      - Returns "true" for valid element and "false" for unknown HTML element.
*/
export function isValid(element) {
  return element.toString() !== "[object HTMLUnknownElement]";
}
```

Is the param an Object or is it something different like `@param {NodeElement}` ?

I have checked https://jsdoc.app/tags-param.html but cannot find the answer for it.

Comment: It should be a [`HTMLElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement). All elements are inherited from this type including [`HTMLUnknownElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLUnknownElement)

Comment: @HaoWu thank you, i guess thats what i am looking for

Comment: @HaoWu I think you should post it as an answer. I was going to say the exact same thing

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek You're right, let me post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be a [`HTMLElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement). All HTML elements are inherited from this type including [`HTMLUnknownElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLUnknownElement)

Also, while you checking it, you could use

```js
export function isValid(element) {
  return !(element instanceof HTMLUnknownElement);
}
```

In case the `toString` function of that element has been overwritten.